# Using Nortel switches for Cisco CCNA

Tags: untagged

I need to purchase some to practice on for my upcoming CCNA-exam. I've found a guy selling some Cisco routers, but he's also saying that he has some Nortel switches he's used for his CCNA and CCNP certification. I don't know the product name of the Nortel switches in question, only that they're 24 and 48 ports.

I know that Nortel is using its own proprietary OS on their switches, and it's sort of similar to IOS, but has anybody here used Nortel for their Cisco certification rather than Cisco equipment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't do it. Some commands are the same and some are different. It will be confusing. Cisco 2950 switches are extremely affordable.

Comment: In the end I decided not to buy the equipment, and continue my search for proper Cisco equipment.

Comment: You should be able to find 2950s for $50 each, or less. They support all of the commands that you need to know for the current ICND1/ICND2 exams. I also recommend [Wendell Odom's books and Network Simulator](http://www.amazon.com/640-802-Official-Library-Simulator-Updated/dp/1587204371/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1357423874&sr=1-1&keywords=odom+simulator+edition); if you study these effectively, you will have no trouble passing your CCNA without purchasing any equipment at all. (You *do* need equipment for CCNP/CCIE.)

Answer (score 3):

That just seems like a bad idea to me. Practice on the vendor equipment for the vendor exam, not another vendor's equipment. You can get Cisco training kits at pretty reasonable prices.

Personally, I've purchased training kits from this vendor and have been pretty pleased:

http://www.certificationkits.com